# Flash Magic error: "Unable to communicate.(in use)Ensure no other applications are using the COM Port. Try raising or lowering the baud rate"

Tags: networking, wine, arm, firmware, embedded-system

I am trying to burn a .hex file on LPC2129 by connecting it through USB wire with my PC by using Flash Magic software on Ubuntu 20.04. The moment I press start on Flash Magic it shows the error below:

```
Unable to communicate.(in use)Ensure no other applications are using the COM Port. Try raising or lowering the baud rate.
```

I have tried many options like:

`ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 ~/.wine/dosdevices/com3` (or any other com port),
earlier it was not creating a symbolic link and was throwing an error:
`ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/lakshya/.wine/dosdevices/com3': File exists`.

But when I used `ln -sf /dev/ttyUSB0 ~/.wine/dosdevices/com3`,
it did not throw any error and executed it.

But again when I pressed the start button on Flash Magic it gave same error:
`Unable to communicate.(in use)Ensure no other applications are using the COM Port. Try raising or lowering the baud rate.`

I have performed steps mentioned in the link below but it did not resolve: [Flash Magic on Ubuntu](http://linuxkernel51.blogspot.com/2017/12/flashmagic-on-ubuntu.html)

Please find the images below too for understanding the query:
[image: Terminal errors]

[image: Flash MAgic errors]

Question:
Is your userid in the same group as `/dev/ttyUSB0? id;stat --format="%G" /dev/ttyUSB0`?

Answer:
By using the commands below:

command1-> `id`

Output - `id=1000(lakshya) gid=1000(lakshya) groups=1000(lakshya),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare)`

command2-> `stat --format="%G" /dev/ttyUSB0`

Output -  `dialout`

Comment: Is your userid in the same group as `/dev/ttyUSB0`? `id;stat --format="%G" /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: @waltinator by using this command 'id' i am getting: id=1000(lakshya) gid=1000(lakshya) groups=1000(lakshya),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare) and after using 'stat --format="%G" /dev/ttyUSB0' command i have got an output as 'dialout'.

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read, ignored by AskUbuntu's indexing system, and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]. Once you do that, I'll offer a suggestion.

Comment: @waltinator Kindly suggest if its fine now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your userid to the `dialout` group. An `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0` will show that group members have `rw-` access.

Read `man adduser`, and do

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

Once that is done, either use `newgrp dialout` (Read `man newgrp`) to create a process with the new group, or logout and login again to endow all your processes with the new group.